# The file format and extension of don't match: excel generated with javascript

Tags: javascript, excel

I know there is a lot of ways to download/create excel from javascript like sheetjs and others. I checked all stackoverflow questions related, or they using Activex (only works on IE), or the answers are outdated. But still, I can create a file and download it, but when I try to open, it gives always these error:

[image]

How can I change the format and extension to be the same? / There is a ways to bypass these error?

```js
const data_type = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,';

function createXLSFromJson() {

 var xml = '<html xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"><head><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>Error Messages</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:Panes></x:Panes></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml></head><body>';

 xml += '<table><thead><tr>';

 xml += '<td width="300" valign="top"><b>Location</b></td>'; // Location
 xml += '<td width="180" valign="top"><b>Catchment area</b></td>'; // Catchment area
 xml += '<td width="180" valign="top"><b>Towns</b></td>'; // Towns
 xml += '<td width="180" valign="top"><b>Population</b></td>'; // Population
 xml += '<td width="180" valign="top"><b>Average Income per inhabitant</b></td>'; // Average Income per inhabitant
 xml += '</tr><tr>';
 xml += '<td>Location</td><td>catchment time 1</td>';
 xml += '</tr></thead></table></body></html>';

 var link = document.createElement("a");
 link.download = "export.xls";
 link.href = data_type + btoa(xml);
 link.click();
}
```

```html
<button onclick="createXLSFromJson()">click here</button>
```

Comment: Have you tried saving as `.xlsx`?

Comment: Google for "Office extension hardening" and you can find out all about this.  You're not sending a native Excel file format, and there are security concerns connected with that.

Comment: Yup, same problem with .xlsx

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same error and can solve it using this data type:

```
const data_type = 'data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;base64';
```